# Corr function in Oracle

Tags: oracle, correlation

is it possible to create correlation in Oracle between rows in two tables? 
I have two tables - one with temperatures, another with humidity in different cities in time. 
I would like to create correlation (CORR function) between temp and humidity in given city between some dates, but I'm not sure how to do it.

Thanks for your help!

desc TEMP;

```
CITY   VALUE       DATE
C1      19.6       2017-10-02 19:01
C3      10.6       2017-10-02 19:01
C3      12         2017-10-02 19:01
C2      10.1        2017-10-02 19:01
C2      18         2017-10-02 19:01
C2      10         2017-10-02 19:01
C1      21.6       2017-10-02 20:01
C1      10.6       2017-10-02 20:01
```

desc HUMIDITY;

```
CITY   VALUE       DATE
C1      60         2017-10-02 19:01
C3      70         2017-10-02 19:01
C3      62         2017-10-02 19:01
C2      67         2017-10-02 19:01
C2      68         2017-10-02 19:01
C2      70         2017-10-02 19:01
C1      71.6       2017-10-02 20:01
C1      70.6       2017-10-02 20:01
```

I would like to choose CITY and DATE range (between some dates) to calculate correlation between VALUE in TEMP and HUMIDTY.

Comment: Could you provide your table structure, some sample data, and expected results?

Comment: I edited the description

Comment: As long as you have ways to join the tables; you should be able to.  Though, Not sure I fully understand the question but maybe... `SELECT T.City, T.Date, Corr(T.Value, H.Value) FROM TEMP T INNER JOIN HUMIDITY H on T.City = H.City and T.Date = H.Date GROUP BY T.City, T.Date`

Comment: yes, this is something that I want to achieve! (maybe more, adding date range), but when Im trying to test your solution right now I got:
column ambiguously defined : (

Comment: Okay I managed to fix it, but actually when I group by both city and date there is no result in Corr (empty field), when I change to group only by city then it shows some results.

Anyway thanks for the help so far!!!

Comment: would need to remove date from the select/group by and enter  a date range `where date between '2017-10-01' and '201711-02'`

Comment: You shouldn't group by city AND date - then you will end up with a single observation pair, in which case the correlation is undefined. Do you only need to measure time correlation, or also cross-sectional correlation? The former is what you describe (FIX the city, measure correlation over time). The latter is, FIX the date, measure the correlation over cities (at one point in time). Both may be of interest to your end users, you may want to ask them to find out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CTE (With)   below is used to simulate your two tables:

```
With Temp (City, value, Mdate) as (SELECT 'C1', 19.6, to_date('2017-10-02 19:01','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
SELECT 'C3', 10.6, to_date('2017-10-02 19:01','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'C3', 12, to_date('2017-10-02 19:01','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'C2', 10.1, to_date('2017-10-02 19:01','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'C2', 18, to_date('2017-10-02 19:01','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'C2', 10, to_date('2017-10-02 19:01','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'C1', 21.6, to_date('2017-10-02 20:01','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'C1', 10.6, to_date('2017-10-02 20:01','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') FROM DUAL),

Humidity (City, value, mDate) as (SELECT 'C1', 60, to_date('2017-10-02 19:01','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'C3', 70, to_date('2017-10-02 19:01','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'C3', 62, to_date('2017-10-02 19:01','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'C2', 67, to_date('2017-10-02 19:01','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'C2', 68, to_date('2017-10-02 19:01','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'C2', 70, to_date('2017-10-02 19:01','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'C1', 71.6, to_date('2017-10-02 20:01','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'C1', 70.6, to_date('2017-10-02 20:01','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') FROM DUAL)


--Now this is the query to coorlate the two values between two dates using the two CTE's above. 

SELECT T.City, Corr(T.Value, H.Value)  corr
FROM TEMP T 
INNER JOIN HUMIDITY H 
  on T.City = H.City 
 and T.mDate = H.mDate 
 WHERE T.mDate between to_date('2017-10-01','YYYY-MM-DD') and to_date('2017-11-02','YYYY-MM-DD') 
GROUP BY T.City
```

Giving us:

```
+------+--------------------------------------------+
| City |                    Corr                    |
+------+--------------------------------------------+
| C2   |                                          0 |
| C1   | -0.272343645393387267052058460609147833569 |
| C3   |                                          0 |
+------+--------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you! I will test it today! I have to rewrite it into procedure as this will be used with apex